# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in android studio

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I am getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in android studio ,when i add a new class in my project that class is not detected by the rest of the code(It is not giving any compile time errors by not working as expected).
In this case I have added a UtilDateTime class which is giving java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError. Please help me out this probably does not seem to be a coding problem but something related to the libraries I am using(Though i am not sure of the sorce of problem).

The Log is showing this :-

```
    08-08 17:03:36.832  19979-20179/com.indiacom.salondemo E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.indiacom.salondemo.utilities.UtilDateTime
            at com.indiacom.salondemo.asynctask.CalendarApiAsyncTask.getDataFromApi(CalendarApiAsyncTask.java:86)
            at com.indiacom.salondemo.asynctask.CalendarApiAsyncTask.doInBackground(CalendarApiAsyncTask.java:45)
            at com.indiacom.salondemo.asynctask.CalendarApiAsyncTask.doInBackground(CalendarApiAsyncTask.java:22)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
            at                                
android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
```

This is my code :-

AppointmentActivity class:-

```
package com.indiacom.salondemo;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http.AndroidHttp;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.ExponentialBackOff;


import com.google.api.services.calendar.CalendarScopes;
import com.indiacom.salondemo.asynctask.CalendarApiAsyncTask;
import com.indiacom.salondemo.utilities.UtilDateTime;

import android.accounts.AccountManager;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class AppointmentActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * A Google Calendar API service object used to access the API.
     * Note: Do not confuse this class with API library's model classes, which
     * represent specific data structures.
     */
    public com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar mService;

    GoogleAccountCredential credential;
    private TextView mStatusText;
    private TextView mResultsText;
    final HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
    final JsonFactory jsonFactory = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    public static final int REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER = 1000;
   public static final int REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION = 1001;
    static final int REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES = 1002;
    private static final String PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME = "accountName";
    private static final String[] SCOPES = { CalendarScopes.CALENDAR_READONLY };

    /**
     * Create the main activity.
     * @param savedInstanceState previously saved instance data.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LinearLayout activityLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        activityLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
        activityLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        activityLayout.setPadding(16, 16, 16, 16);

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams tlp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        mStatusText = new TextView(this);
        mStatusText.setLayoutParams(tlp);
        mStatusText.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        mStatusText.setText("Retrieving data...");
        activityLayout.addView(mStatusText);

        mResultsText = new TextView(this);
        mResultsText.setLayoutParams(tlp);
        mResultsText.setPadding(16, 16, 16, 16);
        mResultsText.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        mResultsText.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        activityLayout.addView(mResultsText);

        setContentView(activityLayout);

        // Initialize credentials and service object.
        SharedPreferences settings = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(SCOPES))
                .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff())
                .setSelectedAccountName(settings.getString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, null));

        mService = new com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Builder(
                transport, jsonFactory, credential)
                .setApplicationName("Google Calendar API Android Quickstart")
                .build();
    }

    /**
     * Called whenever this activity is pushed to the foreground, such as after
     * a call to onCreate().
     */
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
            refreshResults();
        } else {
            mStatusText.setText("Google Play Services required: " +
                    "after installing, close and relaunch this app.");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called when an activity launched here (specifically, AccountPicker
     * and authorization) exits, giving you the requestCode you started it with,
     * the resultCode it returned, and any additional data from it.
     * @param requestCode code indicating which activity result is incoming.
     * @param resultCode code indicating the result of the incoming
     *     activity result.
     * @param data Intent (containing result data) returned by incoming
     *     activity result.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(
            int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch(requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES:
                if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                    isGooglePlayServicesAvailable();
                }
                break;
            case REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null &&
                        data.getExtras() != null) {
                    String accountName =
                            data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
                    if (accountName != null) {
                        credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
                        SharedPreferences settings =
                                getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                        editor.putString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName);
                        editor.commit();
                    }
                } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                    mStatusText.setText("Account unspecified.");
                }
                break;
            case REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION:
                if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                    chooseAccount();
                }
                break;
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    /**
     * Attempt to get a set of data from the Google Calendar API to display. If the
     * email address isn't known yet, then call chooseAccount() method so the
     * user can pick an account.
     */
    private void refreshResults() {
        if (credential.getSelectedAccountName() == null) {
            chooseAccount();
        } else {
            if (isDeviceOnline()) {
               new CalendarApiAsyncTask(this).execute();
            } else {
                mStatusText.setText("No network connection available.");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Clear any existing Google Calendar API data from the TextView and update
     * the header message; called from background threads and async tasks
     * that need to update the UI (in the UI thread).
     */
    public void clearResultsText() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mStatusText.setText("Retrieving data…");
                mResultsText.setText("");
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Fill the data TextView with the given List of Strings; called from
     * background threads and async tasks that need to update the UI (in the
     * UI thread).
     * @param dataStrings a List of Strings to populate the main TextView with.
     */
    public void updateResultsText(final ArrayList<UtilDateTime> dataStrings) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (dataStrings == null) {
                    mStatusText.setText("Error retrieving data!");
                } else if (dataStrings.size() == 0) {
                    mStatusText.setText("No data found.");
                }else{
                    mStatusText.setText("Data retrieved using" +
                            " the Google Calendar API:");

                    String sss=dataStrings.get(0).getmDate();

                    Log.d("Sample String:","String sss="+sss);

                    mResultsText.setText(sss);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Show a status message in the list header TextView; called from background
     * threads and async tasks that need to update the UI (in the UI thread).
     * @param message a String to display in the UI header TextView.
     */
    public void updateStatus(final String message) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mStatusText.setText(message);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Starts an activity in Google Play Services so the user can pick an
     * account.
     */
    private void chooseAccount() {
        startActivityForResult(
                credential.newChooseAccountIntent(), REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
    }

    /**
     * Checks whether the device currently has a network connection.
     * @return true if the device has a network connection, false otherwise.
     */
    private boolean isDeviceOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager connMgr =
                (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected());
    }

    /**
     * Check that Google Play services APK is installed and up to date. Will
     * launch an error dialog for the user to update Google Play Services if
     * possible.
     * @return true if Google Play Services is available and up to
     *     date on this device; false otherwise.
     */
    private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
        final int connectionStatusCode =
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(connectionStatusCode)) {
            showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(connectionStatusCode);
            return false;
        } else if (connectionStatusCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS ) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Display an error dialog showing that Google Play Services is missing
     * or out of date.
     * @param connectionStatusCode code describing the presence (or lack of)
     *     Google Play Services on this device.
     */
   public void showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(
            final int connectionStatusCode) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(
                        connectionStatusCode,
                        AppointmentActivity.this,
                        REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES);
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

CalenderApiAsyncTask class :-

```
package com.indiacom.salondemo.asynctask;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthIOException;
import com.google.api.client.util.DateTime;

import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.*;
import com.indiacom.salondemo.AppointmentActivity;
import com.indiacom.salondemo.AppointmentActivity;
import com.indiacom.salondemo.utilities.UtilDateTime;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * An asynchronous task that handles the Google Calendar API call.
 * Placing the API calls in their own task ensures the UI stays responsive.
 */
public class CalendarApiAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private AppointmentActivity mActivity;

    ArrayList<UtilDateTime> mArrList;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param activity MainActivity that spawned this task.
     */
    public CalendarApiAsyncTask(AppointmentActivity activity) {
        this.mActivity = activity;
    }

    /**
     * Background task to call Google Calendar API.
     *
     * @param params no parameters needed for this task.
     */
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            mActivity.clearResultsText();
            mActivity.updateResultsText(getDataFromApi());

        } catch (final GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException availabilityException) {
            mActivity.showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(
                    availabilityException.getConnectionStatusCode());

        } catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException userRecoverableException) {
            mActivity.startActivityForResult(
                    userRecoverableException.getIntent(),
                    AppointmentActivity.REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            mActivity.updateStatus("The following error occurred:\n" +
                    e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Fetch a list of the next 10 events from the primary calendar.
     *
     * @return List of Strings describing returned events.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private ArrayList<UtilDateTime> getDataFromApi() throws IOException {
        // List the next 10 events from the primary calendar.
        DateTime now = new DateTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
        List<String> eventStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
        Events events = mActivity.mService.events().list("primary")
                .setMaxResults(10)
                .setTimeMin(now)
                .setOrderBy("startTime")
                .setSingleEvents(true)
                .execute();
        List<Event> items = events.getItems();

        mArrList= new ArrayList<UtilDateTime>();

        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {

           UtilDateTime  objectForDateTime=new UtilDateTime();
            objectForDateTime.setmDate("12-7-2015");
            objectForDateTime.setmTime("12.00");
            mArrList.add(objectForDateTime);

        }


       Log.e("arraylist::","list:"+mArrList.get(0).getmDate());
//
//        for (Event event : items) {
//            DateTime start = event.getStart().getDateTime();
//            if (start == null) {
//                // All-day events don't have start times, so just use
//                // the start date.
//                start = event.getStart().getDate();
//            }
//            eventStrings.add(
//                    String.format("%s (%s)", event.getSummary(), start));
//        }
        return mArrList;
    }

}
```

UtilDateTime class :-

```
    package com.indiacom.salondemo.utilities;

/**
 * Created by cloud1 on 7/8/15.
 */
public class UtilDateTime {

    String mDate, mTime;

    public UtilDateTime()
    {

    }

    public UtilDateTime(String mDate, String mTime) {
        this.mDate = mDate;
        this.mTime = mTime;
    }

    public String getmDate() {
        return mDate;
    }

    public void setmDate(String mDate) {
        this.mDate = mDate;
    }

    public String getmTime() {
        return mTime;
    }

    public void setmTime(String mTime) {
        this.mTime = mTime;
    }
}
```